# How can I run a query against a series of value pairs and store the results in a temporary table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, parameters, parameter-passing

Assume that I have an array of values:

(A1,a1, A2,a2, A3,a3, A4,a4....., An,an)

How should I automate and run the below TSQL query against the (A1,a1..... ,An,an) pairs

```
SELECT COUNT (1)
FROM food
WHERE calories = Ai AND ingredient = ai --i = {1..n}
```

So that each count obtained by (Ai,ai) {i=1..n} will be stored in a temporary table?

Thanks

Comment: In a temp table in the sql database?

Comment: In which form you have `A1,a1, A2,a2, A3,a3, A4,a4....., An,an`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the values in your array into a temp table (I'm going to use the same one for the results later):

```
create table #pairs (
    calories    varchar(50),
    ingredient  varchar(50),
    count       int
)
```

Then, we can get our result in one step:

```
UPDATE p
SET count = x.count
FROM #pairs p inner join
    (   SELECT f.calories, f.ingredient, COUNT(*) as count
        FROM food f inner join
            #pairs p ON f.calories = p.calories and f.ingredient = p.ingredient
        GROUP BY f.calories, f.ingredient
    ) x ON p.calories = x.calories and p.ingredient = x.ingredient


select * from #pairs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with dynamix SQL, something like this:

```
declare @count int, @limit int
select @count = 0, @limit = 5 -- limit is n

declare @sqlcmd varchar(300)

-- table
create table #result (
combination varchar(10),
total int
)

while @count < @limit
begin
  select @sqlcmd = 'insert into #results select distinct "(" + ingredient + "," + calories + ")", count(*) from food where calories = A' + convert(varchar, @count) + ' and ingredient = a' + convert(varchar, @count)

  exec(@sqlcmd)

  select @count = @count + 1
end
```

Comment: I'm assuming the array with A1, A2, A3.. An ingredients and a1, a2, a3.. an calories but if it's not that I can change it, just say something here :)